# Going back to page won't reload jQuery with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am just new to jQuery mobile.

I have a site I am building and I want each page in a separate HTML file.

When I goto a page the first time jQuery fires and binds my events as expected. However, when I go back to this page, jQuery does not bind anything.

Changes page to login screen:

```
$.mobile.changePage("/screens/login.html");
```

Login Screen:

```
< div data-role="page" id="login" data-add-back-btn="true" data-dom-cache="false">
    <script src="/resources/scripts/login.js"></script>
    < div data-role="header" >
        <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">&nbsp;</h1>
        <a id="btRegister" data-icon="edit">Register</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

login.js contains jQuery that binds an event to the btRegister element:

```
$(function () {
   $("#btRegister").click(function () {
       $.mobile.changePage("/screens/login.html");
    });
});
```

This works fine the first time. I click the login button and am taken to the login page as expected.

On the login page I have almost exactly the same thing that links me back to the register page.

Upon returning to the register page, the event is not bound and the click event does nothing.

I have tried everything including  reloadPage: true and data-dom-cache="false" nothing is getting this working it seems bleak.

I would appreciate some input from someone more familiar with jQuery mobile to tell me where I went wrong. Should I just stick to a single HTML page? I really like the ability to make my app more modular with multiple HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

This is working properly. The main problem I was having was the class structure on my partial page javascript class and the name spacing i was using.

I was using a static class so this worked the first time, but needed to instantiate the class every time.

I wired a hook on my global js file that calls a common function:

```
$(document).bind("pageshow", function (event, ui) {
    pageInit();
});
```

I then have a pageInt() on all my partial page scripts that instantiates a new instance of the page object:

```
function pageInit() {
    var myRegisterPage = new registerPage();
    myRegisterPage.init();
};

function registerPage() {
}

registerPage.prototype = {

    init: function () {
        $("#btLogin").click(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("/screens/login.html");
    });
}
```

}

It was very stressful.

Comment: note that with this, you will add multiple click event on login button, because `pageshow` will run `pageInit` function everytime page is shown better use `$("#btn").off("click").on("click", function`.

Comment: this is what I expected to happen, but for some reason it doesn't. If this was the case, I would have no need to rerun the Init function for each page on load.